# How to add an total line to a query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have some queries that I need to add a total line at the end with the sums of columns with numeric values. I already tried the rollup statement but without success. Can someone help me?

I'm using an Oracle database.

Here's a simple example:

```
Create table funcionario_movimentos 
(
    id_funcionario number(7),
    cod_verba varchar2(4),
    valor number(13,2),
    mes_competencia number(2),
    ano_competencia number(4)
);
```

```
insert into funcionario_movimentos values (4358,'V003',8500.00,12,2022)
insert into funcionario_movimentos values (3521,'V003',11400.00,12,2022)
insert into funcionario_movimentos values (3242,'V003',18200.00,12,2022)
```

```
SELECT 
    fm.id_funcionario, fm.cod_verba, fm.valor
FROM 
    funcionario_movimentos fm
WHERE 
    mes_competencia = 12
    AND ano_competencia = 2022
    AND cod_verba = 'V003'
    AND id_funcionario IN (4358, 3521, 3242);
```

The result is as below:

| Id_funcionario | Cod_verba | Valor |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4358 | V003 | 8500.00 |
| 3521 | V003 | 11400.00 |
| 3242 | V003 | 18200.00 |

But expected was:

| Id_funcionario | Cod_verba | Valor |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4358 | V003 | 8500.00 |
| 3521 | V003 | 11400.00 |
| 3242 | V003 | 18200.00 |
|  |  | 38100.00 |

As we can see I need the total only in the columns with values.

Comment: https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-rollup/

Comment: `group by grouping sets ((id_funcionario,cod_verba),())`. See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6c57f6/4

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use partial rollup (see line #8), to reduce number of subtotals:

```
SQL> SELECT fm.id_funcionario, fm.cod_verba, SUM(fm.valor) valor
  2  FROM funcionario_movimentos fm
  3  WHERE mes_competencia = 12
  4    AND ano_competencia = 2022
  5    AND cod_verba = 'V003'
  6    AND id_funcionario IN (4358,3521,3242)
  7  --
  8  GROUP BY fm.cod_verba, ROLLUP (fm.id_funcionario);

ID_FUNCIONARIO COD_      VALOR
-------------- ---- ----------
          4358 V003       8500
          3521 V003      11400
          3242 V003      18200
               V003      38100

SQL>
```

Because, if you applied `rollup` to all non-aggregated columns, you'd get additional subtotals:

```
  <snip>
  8  GROUP BY ROLLUP (fm.id_funcionario, fm.cod_verba);

ID_FUNCIONARIO COD_      VALOR
-------------- ---- ----------
          4358 V003       8500
          3521 V003      11400
          3242 V003      18200
          4358            8500
          3521           11400
          3242           18200
                         38100

7 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Without any aggregates, you'd have to rollup all 3 columns and get result you really don't want:

```
SQL> SELECT fm.id_funcionario, fm.cod_verba, fm.valor
  <snip>
  8  GROUP BY ROLLUP (fm.id_funcionario, fm.cod_verba, fm.valor);

ID_FUNCIONARIO COD_      VALOR
-------------- ---- ----------
          4358 V003       8500
          3521 V003      11400
          3242 V003      18200
          4358 V003
          3521 V003
          3242 V003
          4358
          3521
          3242


10 rows selected.

SQL>
```

---

Just for amusement, if you use SQL*Plus, you can `compute` total using your "original" query as

```
SQL> break on report
SQL> compute sum of valor on report
SQL>
SQL> SELECT fm.id_funcionario, fm.cod_verba, fm.valor
  2  FROM funcionario_movimentos fm
  3  WHERE mes_competencia = 12
  4    AND ano_competencia = 2022
  5    AND cod_verba = 'V003'
  6    AND id_funcionario IN (4358,3521,3242);

ID_FUNCIONARIO COD_      VALOR
-------------- ---- ----------
          4358 V003       8500
          3521 V003      11400
          3242 V003      18200
                    ----------
sum                      38100

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use your query - just add MODEL clause:

```sql
SELECT  ID_FUNCIONARIO, COD_VERBA,  VALOR
FROM    FUNCIONARIO_MOVIMENTOS
WHERE   MES_COMPETENCIA = 12 AND 
        ANO_COMPETENCIA = 2022 AND 
        COD_VERBA = 'V003' AND 
        ID_FUNCIONARIO IN (4358,3521,3242)
MODEL
        Dimension By   (  ID_FUNCIONARIO  )
        Measures       (  Cast(COD_VERBA as VarChar2(12)) "COD_VERBA", VALOR )
        RULES
            ( VALOR[0] = Sum(VALOR)[ANY],
              COD_VERBA[0] = 'Total:'   )
```

R e s u l t:

| ID_FUNCIONARIO | COD_VERBA | VALOR |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4358 | V003 | 8500 |
| 3521 | V003 | 11400 |
| 3242 | V003 | 18200 |
| 0 | Total: | 38100 |

More about MODEL [here](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/10g/r2/prod/bidw/sqlmodel/sqlmodel_otn.htm)

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest answer:

```sql
WITH funcionario_movimentos (id_funcionario, cod_verba, valor, mes_competencia, ano_competencia) AS (
   SELECT 4358, 'V003', 8500.00,  12, 2022 FROM dual UNION
   SELECT 3521, 'V003', 11400.00, 12, 2022 FROM dual UNION
   SELECT 3242, 'V003', 18200.00, 12, 2022 FROM dual
)
SELECT fm.id_funcionario, fm.cod_verba, sum(fm.valor) valor, count(1) nr
FROM   funcionario_movimentos fm
GROUP BY rollup((fm.id_funcionario, fm.cod_verba))
```

Note the double bracket `(( xx ))` around the `rollup()` in order that you group  the "set" of columns together in the rollup.  It's a very subtle detail ;-)

@d_r's answer is super clever, but way overkill unless you're into serious data-warehousing stuff.

[image]